# json_decode (file_get_contents) returns null

Tags: php, json

Im trying to create a json object from my POST data. When i var_dump the $postData i get the folowing result:

```
string(92) "{
  "name" : "bier",
  "city" : "Rotterdam"
  "address": "straat 41"
  "max_persons": "150"
}"
```

When i var_dump $json i get NULL

this is my code:

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($postData);

var_dump($postData);
```

This is what i am sending to my webservice:

```
{
  "name" : "bier",
  "city" : "Rotterdam"
  "address": "straat 41"
  "max_persons": "150"
}
```

Why is Json_decode returning NULL?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/json_decode):

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Now see [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/):

> ```
> Parse error on line 3:
> ... "city": "Rotterdam""address": "straat 4
> -----------------------^
> Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
> ```

The JSON is invalid. There is a comma missing between  `"Rotterdam"` and `"address"`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma in your json, after "straat 41".

{ "name" : "bier", "city" : "Rotterdam" "address": "straat 41", "max_persons": "150" }

Use jsonlint.com to validate the json you are trying to decode.