# Why is my API returning NULL while using PHP's `json_decode(file_get_contents($link),true);`

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to pull crypto-mining data from the server's API; however, when I run the `.php` file, it comes back with null:

HTML/PHP

```
$meow_base_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($meow_base_api), true);
var_dump($meow_base_data);
```

`var_dump` only says "NULL" - no other information.

FYI - I did check [json_decode (file_get_contents) returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879363/json-decode-file-get-contents-returns-null) and used the JSON Lint link - the JSON comes back as "Valid".

Here is the `JSON` header info from the `API`:

```
"version": "0.0.3",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

I've also tried without the decode and doing:

```
file_get_contents($meow_base_api);
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

...which comes back with...

> array(14) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879363/json-decode-file-get-contents-returns-null)=> string(20) "Server: nginx/1.21.6" [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5CLc.png)=> string(35) "Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 20:01:08 GMT" [3]=> string(30) "Content-Type: application/json" [4]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [5]=> string(21) "x-powered-by: Express" [6]=> string(30) "access-control-allow-origin: *" [7]=> string(131) "access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods" [8]=> string(33) "access-control-allow-methods: GET" [9]=> string(21) "vary: Accept-Encoding" [10]=> string(22) "content-encoding: gzip" [11]=> string(25) "cache-control: max-age=20" [12]=> string(22) "apicache-store: memory" [13]=> string(23) "apicache-version: 1.6.3" }

I've tried the API link with and without the 's' (HTTP vs HTTPS) - no difference either way.

FULL `API` in response to a comment:

```
{"version":"0.0.3","statusCode":200,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET","Content-Type":"application/json"},"body":{"primary":{"config":{"coin":"Meowcoin","symbol":"MEWC","algorithm":"kawpow","paymentInterval":10800,"minPayment":10,"recipientFee":0.01},"blocks":{"valid":1098,"invalid":0},"shares":{"valid":1297,"stale":0,"invalid":0},"hashrate":{"shared":4988807485.295822,"solo":0},"network":{"difficulty":5315.531682902409,"hashrate":363014296311.9665,"height":66171},"payments":{"last":1666380432093,"next":1666391232093,"total":3246666.94166398},"status":{"effort":18.788831312282458,"luck":{"luck1":310.69,"luck10":124.89,"luck100":103.61},"miners":25,"workers":35}},"auxiliary":{"config":{"coin":"","symbol":"","algorithm":"","paymentInterval":0,"minPayment":0,"recipientFee":0},"blocks":{"valid":0,"invalid":0},"shares":{"valid":0,"stale":0,"invalid":0},"hashrate":{"shared":0,"solo":0},"network":{"difficulty":0,"hashrate":0,"height":0},"payments":{"last":0,"next":0,"total":0},"status":{"effort":0,"luck":{"luck1":0,"luck10":0,"luck100":0},"miners":0,"workers":0}}}}
```

Here is what it shows when I `var_dump` without the decode:

> [image: file_get_char output]

The script for this I'm using is:

```
$fgc = file_get_contents($meow_base_api);
var_dump($fgc);
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON. That's why you get a NULL on decode. Curly braces are missing around.

Comment: There are curly brackets on the full thing - I cut it for just the header portion.... I'll tweak the question.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're getting HTTP headers in JSON, that doesn't make any sense. Is that actually what the API endpoint is returning in the response body? Can you output the raw value of `file_get_contents($meow_base_api)` without trying to decode it first?

Comment: added response to the question.

Comment: The clue is in the response headers you dumped: `content-encoding: gzip` -- the value you get from `file_get_contents()` is gzip'ed (as you can see by the raw binary data you see when dumping `$fgc`) and needs to be deflated before passing it through `json_decode()`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan - can you throw that in an answer with some documentation so I can learn this better please?

Comment: I think I figured it out - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php - had to use `gzdecode`. it's now showing a language I can understand :). Thank you for your help - if you throw it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Just to correct my previous comment: the data needs to be **inflated** (or decompressed). The server is sending **deflated** (or compressed) data.

Comment: Note, if you use curl or guzzle or pretty much any other HTTP-based library instead of `file_get_contents()`, this decoding will be done automatically and transparently for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `json_decode()` returns `NULL` and you're sure you're getting a response, the first debugging step should be to look at what you're passing into the function.

So if the result for `$meow_base_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($meow_base_api), true);` is `NULL`, see what you're actually getting by running `var_dump(file_get_contents($meow_base_api));`.

In your case, the result of this appears to be binary data. The clue as to what sort of data this is, is in the response headers:

`Content-Type: application/json` but combined with `content-encoding: gzip`. So you're getting a Gzip'ed JSON response. You need to un-gzip the response before you can pass it through `json_decode()`.

Unfortunately, this is not as straightforward as it sounds. Although PHP does come with several functions to decompress Gzip-data ([`gzdecode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php), [`gzinflate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php), [`gzuncompress()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) and [`zlib_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zlib-decode.php)), it is usually a case of trial-and-error before you find the one you need to use.

Sometimes, none of these functions are able to decompress the data out of the box. This can happen if the server uses a specific method of compression that browsers understand natively but PHP's functions don't. In this case, there will be a 10-byte prefix and an 8-byte suffix to the compressed data, so you can try the functions like this for example: `$data = gzinflate(substr($raw_data, 10, -8));`.

There is a relatively easy workaround for this problem though: use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-examples) instead of `file_get_contents()` (use the [`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-parameters)). cURL has native support for compressed responses as long as the `content-encoding` header is present, and will transparently decompress the response body without you having to do anything.